# Invalid column in unpivot CTE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am getting the error `Invalid column name MERCHANDISE_AMT'.` on the below CTE unpivot query. I am selecting in `MERCHANDISE_AMT` in both queries so I do not understand why it's coming up as invalid. What am I overlooking here? If I take MERCHANDISE_AMT out of the `unpivot` than it runs, but I need to use this column for unpivoting. (unpivot (value FOR col IN (<strike>MERCHANDISE_AMT,</strike> FREIGHT_AMT, SALETX_AMT)) u

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID, A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, 
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE 
                  WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    AND VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
                    AND VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM)                                                                            
           THEN 'ITEM' ELSE 'MISCELLANEOUS' END AS LINE_TYPE , A.MERCHANDISE_AMT, CASE WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(24),A.QTY_VCHR) = '0' THEN '' ELSE B.QTY_VCHR END AS INVOICE_QTY, CASE WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(24),A.UNIT_PRICE) = '0' THEN '' ELSE A.UNIT_PRICE END AS UNIT_PRICE , A.UNIT_OF_MEASURE, REPLACE(A.DESCR,'"','') AS DESCR , '' AS BLANK1, '' AS BLANK2--A.PO_ID, A.LINE_NBR,
, ''AS BLANK3, ''AS BLANK4, --A.SCHED_NBR, B.PO_DIST_LINE_NUM, 
''AS BLANK5,    
 ''AS BLANK6,''AS BLANK7,''AS BLANK777,''AS BLANK8,''AS BLANK9,''AS BLANK10,''AS BLANK11,''AS BLANK12, 
 F.ORACLE_ENTITY + '.' + F.ORACLE_LOCATION + '.' + CASE WHEN B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL IN ('90000', '90032', '90059') AND H.DEPTID = '741' THEN H.COST_CENTER
                                                       WHEN B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL = '90000' AND H.DEPTID = '956' THEN H.COST_CENTER
                                                       WHEN B.DEPTID IN ('882', '883', '884', '885', '886', '803' , '887', '888') THEN '676'
                                                       WHEN B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL = '14000' AND H.DEPTID = '881' THEN '000'
                                                       WHEN B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL = '14000' AND H.DEPTID = '889' THEN '950'
                                                       WHEN B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL = '11000' AND H.DEPTID = '775' THEN '000'
                                                       WHEN B.DEPTID = '' THEN '000'
                                                       ELSE B.DEPTID END  
+ '.' + B.ACCOUNT + '.' + ISNULL(G.ORACLE_PROJECT_CODE,'000000000.') + ISNULL(NULLIF(B.AFFILIATE, ''), '00000.') + '.000.' + '000000' AS SEGMENTS , 

''AS BLANK13, '2021/05/31' AS DATE1, ''AS BLANK14,''AS BLANK15,''AS BLANK16,''AS BLANK17, ''AS BLANK18, --A.SHIPTO_ID
 ''AS BLANK19,''AS BLANK199,''AS BLANK1999,''AS BLANK20,''AS BLANK21,''AS BLANK211,''AS BLANK22,''AS BLANK23,''AS BLANK24,''AS BLANK25,''AS BLANK26,''AS BLANK27,''AS BLANK28,''AS BLANK29,''AS BLANK30,''AS BLANK31,
 
  ''AS BLANK134, 
  ''AS BLANK32, ''AS BLANK33, ''AS BLANK34,  --A.SALETX_AMT --<--IS THIS THE RIGHT FIELD?
 ''AS BLANK35, ''AS BLANK36, --B.QTY_VCHR, 
'N'AS BLANK37, ''AS BLANK38,''AS BLANK39,''AS BLANK40,''AS BLANK41,''AS BLANK411,''AS BLANK42, ''AS BLANK43, ''AS BLANK44,''AS BLANK45,''AS BLANK46,''AS BLANK47,''AS BLANK48,''AS BLANK49,''AS BLANK50,''AS BLANK51,''AS BLANK52,''AS BLANK53,''AS BLANK54,''AS BLANK55,''AS BLANK56,''AS BLANK57,''AS BLANK58,''AS BLANK59,''AS BLANK60,''AS BLANK61,''AS BLANK62,''AS BLANK63,''AS BLANK64,''AS BLANK65,''AS BLANK66,''AS BLANK67,''AS BLANK68,''AS BLANK69,''AS BLANK70,''AS BLANK71,''AS BLANK72,''AS BLANK73,''AS BLANK74,''AS BLANK75,''AS BLANK76,''AS BLANK77,''AS BLANK78,''AS BLANK79,''AS BLANK80,
''AS BLANK81,''AS BLANK82,''AS BLANK83,''AS BLANK84,''AS BLANK85,''AS BLANK86,''AS BLANK87,''AS BLANK88,''AS BLANK89,''AS BLANK90,''AS BLANK91,''AS BLANK92,''AS BLANK93,''AS BLANK94,''AS BLANK95,''AS BLANK96,''AS BLANK97,''AS BLANK98,''AS BLANK99,''AS BLANK100,''AS BLANK101,''AS BLANK102,''AS BLANK103,''AS BLANK104,''AS BLANK105,''AS BLANK106,''AS BLANK107,''AS BLANK108,''AS BLANK109,''AS BLANK110,''AS BLANK111,''AS BLANK112,''AS BLANK113,''AS BLANK114,''AS BLANK115,''AS BLANK116,''AS BLANK117,''AS BLANK118,''AS BLANK119,''AS BLANK120,''AS BLANK121,''AS BLANK122,''AS BLANK123,''AS BLANK124,''AS BLANK125,''AS BLANK126,''AS BLANK127,''AS BLANK128,''AS BLANK129,''AS BLANK130,''AS BLANK131,'' AS BLANK132
, C.SALETX_AMT, C.FREIGHT_AMT
                                                                                                 
FROM PS_VOUCHER_LINE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_DISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD D ON D.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND D.WTHD_ENTITY = 'IRS'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VCHR_LINE_WTHD DD ON DD.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT AND DD.VOUCHER_ID = D.VOUCHER_ID AND DD.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND DD.WTHD_ENTITY = 'PA'
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VENDOR E ON E.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND E.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudXWalk F ON F.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND (F.DEPTID = 'All' OR F.DEPTID = B.DEPTID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudCostCenter H ON H.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_GL AND H.DEPTID = B.DEPTID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #CloudProjectCodes G ON G.PS_PROJECT_CODE = B.PROJECT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID

WHERE C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
AND C.ACCOUNTING_DT < '06-01-2021'    
AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
AND C.ENTRY_STATUS <> 'X'
 AND C.MATCH_STATUS_VCHR = 'M'
 AND C.APPR_STATUS = 'A'    
 AND B.VOUCHER_ID = '00720667' )

 SELECT INVOICE_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM - 1 + row_number() over (PARTITION BY INVOICE_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM ORDER BY VOUCHER_LINE_NUM) AS VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, 
LINE_TYPE, MERCHANDISE_AMT, INVOICE_QTY, UNIT_PRICE, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, DESCR , BLANK1, BLANK2--A.PO_ID, A.LINE_NBR,
, BLANK3, BLANK4, 
BLANK5, BLANK6,BLANK7,BLANK777,BLANK8,BLANK9,BLANK10,BLANK11,BLANK12, 
 SEGMENTS, BLANK13, DATE1, BLANK14,BLANK15,BLANK16,BLANK17, BLANK18,
 BLANK19,BLANK199,BLANK1999,BLANK20,BLANK21,BLANK211,BLANK22,BLANK23,BLANK24,BLANK25,BLANK26,BLANK27,BLANK28,
 BLANK29,BLANK30,BLANK31,
 BLANK133,
 BLANK134, BLANK32, BLANK33, BLANK34,  
 BLANK35, BLANK36,  
BLANK37, BLANK38,BLANK39,BLANK40,BLANK41,BLANK411,BLANK42, BLANK43, BLANK44,BLANK45,BLANK46,BLANK47,BLANK48,BLANK49,BLANK50,BLANK51,BLANK52,BLANK53,BLANK54,BLANK55,BLANK56,BLANK57,BLANK58,BLANK59,BLANK60,BLANK61,BLANK62,BLANK63,BLANK64,BLANK65,BLANK66,BLANK67,BLANK68,BLANK69,BLANK70,BLANK71,BLANK72,BLANK73,BLANK74,BLANK75,BLANK76,BLANK77,BLANK78,BLANK79,BLANK80,
BLANK81,BLANK82,BLANK83,BLANK84,BLANK85,BLANK86,BLANK87,BLANK88,BLANK89,BLANK90,BLANK91,BLANK92,BLANK93,BLANK94,BLANK95,BLANK96,BLANK97,BLANK98,BLANK99,BLANK100,BLANK101,BLANK102,BLANK103,BLANK104,BLANK105,BLANK106,BLANK107,BLANK108,BLANK109,BLANK110,BLANK111,BLANK112,BLANK113,BLANK114,BLANK115,BLANK116,BLANK117,BLANK118,BLANK119,BLANK120,BLANK121,BLANK122,BLANK123,BLANK124,BLANK125,BLANK126,BLANK127,BLANK128,BLANK129,BLANK130,BLANK131,BLANK132 , value
FROM CTE
unpivot (value FOR col IN (MERCHANDISE_AMT, FREIGHT_AMT, SALETX_AMT)) u
WHERE value > 0.00
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. I’m guessing 90% of that large SQL statement is irrelevant to your question and your more likely to get help if someone doesn’t have to scroll through loads of code to find the relevant information

Comment: Doesn't help that the formatting is all over the place. You are unpivoting that column, so it isn't available anymore, only `value` and `col` are accessible. For example, you also can't select `FREIGHT_AMT` or `SALETX_AMT`, not sure what you expected

Comment: Pet peeve: `;` is a statement **terminator**; it goes at the **end** of *all* your statements, not the start of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include `MERCHANDISE_AMT` here:

```
unpivot (value FOR col IN (MERCHANDISE_AMT, FREIGHT_AMT, SALETX_AMT)
```

**AND** in your final `SELECT` from the `UNPIVOT` results (4th column result set).

Including it in the `IN` list here means that you are unpivoting the value of this column into your row structure, so you can no longer select its value in your final `SELECT`.

So you need to pick. Do you want to unpivot the values in `MERCHANDISE_AMT`? If so, then leave it in the `IN` list of your `UNPIVOT` and remove it from final `SELECT`. If not, then remove it from your `IN` list and leave it in your final `SELECT`.

Seems like you would likely benefit from reading through the Microsoft examples on [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example).